# Spring fails to pickup AOP configuration beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

**Error**

```
Bean 'aopConfiguration' of type [example.config.AopConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5e48431d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors
```

The following beans failed:

- aopConfiguration
- performanceMonitorInterceptor
- performanceMonitorAdvisor

**Config**

```
@Aspect
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Configuration
public class AopConfiguration {

    @Pointcut("execution(* example.service.TimestampService.findAllTimestamps(..))")
    public void monitor() {
    }

    @Bean
    public PerformanceMonitorInterceptor performanceMonitorInterceptor() {
        return new PerformanceMonitorInterceptor(false);
    }

    @Bean
    public Advisor performanceMonitorAdvisor() {
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression("example.config.AopConfiguration.monitor()");
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, performanceMonitorInterceptor());
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
logging:
  file:
    name: log.log
  pattern:
    console: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %msg%n"
  level:
    org.springframework.web: INFO
    example.config.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor: DEBUG
    example: DEBUG
```

Basically no logging or trace information is put to the console.

**dependencies in pom**

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbi3-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbi3-sqlobject</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919498/java-throttling-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.isomorphism</groupId>
            <artifactId>token-bucket</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        logging-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--    integration    test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--         build -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

An aspect should not be its own configuration class because the configuration is for the whole application. Use a separate class for `@Configuration` and let the `@Aspect` just be an aspect (and also make the aspect a `@Component`). Under the hood, proxying for configurations works differently from AOP proxies in Spring. If you are interested in the technical details, read my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56919004/1082681).